# using one javascript function for multiple ids

Tags: javascript, forms

This question might appear very basic.I have three fields in a form,and I want the user to be able to see what he has written when he hovers over an image. Works fine for one field("enter old password").I want to use the Same Javascript function for the other two ("enter new password" , "confirm new password")

```
<form   action="changepw.php" method="post">
  <label>Enter Old Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="oldp" placeholder="old password" id="pw"     required>&nbsp;
  <img  src="\ExTrac\images\eye.png"  onmouseover="mouseoverPass();"     onmouseout="mouseoutPass();" >

  </br></br>

  <label>Enter New Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="newpw" placeholder="new password" id="npw"     required>&nbsp;
  <img  src="\ExTrac\images\eye.png"  onmouseover="mouseoverPass1();"      onmouseout="mouseoutPass1();" >

  </br></br>
  <label>Confirm New Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="cnewpw" placeholder=" confirm new password"    id="cpw" required>&nbsp;
  <img  src="\ExTrac\images\eye.png"  onmouseover="mouseoverPass2();" onmouseout="mouseoutPass2();" >

  </br></br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="style3">   
</form>

<script>
  document.getElementsByClassName("pw").onmouseover = function(){
    mouseoverPass(obj)
  };
  document.getElementsByClassName("pw").onmouseout = function() {  
    mouseoutPass(obj)
  };

  function mouseoverPass(obj) {
    var obj = document.getElementById("pw");
    obj.type = "text";
  }
  function mouseoutPass(obj) {
    var obj = document.getElementById("pw");
    obj.type = "password";
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Give `class` to image elements to be selected using `querySelectorAll / getElementsByClassName`
- Use `previousElementSibling` to get the previous element of the current element
- Remove `inline` event listeners
- Use `[].forEach.call` to use methods of `Array` over object having `length` property

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("form img.eye");
[].forEach.call(elems, function(el) {
  el.onmouseover = mouseoverPass;
  el.onmouseout = mouseoutPass;
});

function mouseoverPass() {
  this.previousElementSibling.type = "text";
}

function mouseoutPass() {
  this.previousElementSibling.type = "password";
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 30x;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form action="changepw.php" method="post">
  <label>Enter Old Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="oldp" placeholder="old password" id="pw" required>&nbsp;
  <img src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/narutofanon/images/3/3d/Eye-Symbol_(1).png" class="eye">
  <br>
  <br>
  <label>Enter New Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="newpw" placeholder="new password" id="npw" required>&nbsp;
  <img src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/narutofanon/images/3/3d/Eye-Symbol_(1).png" class="eye">
  <br>
  <br>
  <label>Confirm New Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="cnewpw" placeholder=" confirm new password" id="cpw" required>&nbsp;
  <img src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/narutofanon/images/3/3d/Eye-Symbol_(1).png" class="eye">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="style3">
```

Comment: I chose to not use sibling in case the html changes. For example you need  to look at node types in some browsers

Answer (score 1):

To change multiple fields you have gotten with getElementsByClassName (which is plural) you need to loop over the collection

You of course also need to give the images the class `pw`

I have added a data-id attribute so you can put the image wherever you want

I also moved the inline event handlers to the window onload event.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var pws = document.getElementsByClassName("pw"); // or document.querySelectorAll(".pw");
  for (var i = 0; i < pws.length; i++) {
    pws[i].onmouseover = function() {
      document.getElementById(this.getAttribute("data-id")).type = "text";
    }
    pws[i].onmouseout = function() {
      document.getElementById(this.getAttribute("data-id")).type = "password";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="changepw.php" method="post">
  <label>Enter Old Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="oldp" placeholder="old password"  id="pw" required>&nbsp;
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Farm-Fresh_eye.png" class="pw" data-id="pw">
  </br>
  </br>
  <label>Enter New Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="newpw" placeholder="new password"  id="npw" required>&nbsp;
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Farm-Fresh_eye.png" class="pw" data-id="npw">
  </br>
  </br>
  <label>Confirm New Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="cnewpw" placeholder=" confirm new password" id="cpw" required>&nbsp;
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Farm-Fresh_eye.png" class="pw" data-id="cpw">
  </br>
  </br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="style3">
```

Comment: Actually OP want it on the mouseover of `image` next to input element..

Comment: Yes, Little ugly but can not help because of  `DOM-structure`

Comment: I came up with a safer construct

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use jQuery for this:

JavaScript

```
$(".show-pw").mouseover(function(){
    this.type = "text";
}).mouseout(function(){
    this.type = "password";
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="password" name="oldp" placeholder="old password" id="pw" class="show-pw" required>
<input type="password" name="newpw" placeholder="new password" id="npw" class="show-pw" required>
<input type="password" name="cnewpw" placeholder=" confirm new password" id="cpw" class="show-pw" required>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/uwtanp3y/11/)

PS. Add `class="show-pw"` to all inputs. DS.